# Visual Studio generates wrong javascript from typescript when saving ts file (works when building project)

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I have strange problem with typescript. I have my enums in separate .ts file and when I save the other file that is using enums, visual studio compiles incorrect javascript, but when I build the project, javascript is generated correctly.

Does anyone know how to get saving working (as it's quite tedious to build project everytime I change .ts file while debugging)?

Example:

MyEnums.ts

```
module MyEnums {
    export const enum MyEnum {
        val1 = 1,
        val2 = 2,
        val3 = 3
    }
}
```

App.ts

```
module App {
    console.log(MyEnums.MyEnum.val1);
}
```

Output (incorrect) when saving App.ts

```
var App;
(function (App) {
    console.log(MyEnums.MyEnum.val1);
})(App || (App = {}));
```

Output (correct) when building project

```
var App;
(function (App) {
    console.log(1 /* val1 */);
})(App || (App = {}));
```

I'm using Typescript 1.4 and Visual Studio 2013 Update 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the TypeScript language service. See [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1916) where there's [a link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14232632/typescriptServices.js) to an updated typescriptservices.js you can patch in to fix the problem.